# Время понедельника, или с чего начинается неделя

Tags: дата, unixtimestamp, php

У меня в базе есть список событий. Таблица имеет `id`, `date`(время) и все остальные данные.

`date` это время непосредственно время события. Время в формате timestamp.

У меня есть php скрипт, который шерстит по базе и, в зависимости от времени, проводит некоторые операции.

Сравнивает конечно if'ами. Он (скрипт) находит события месячной давности (`mktime (0, 0, 0, date('m'),1)`), двух месячной давности (`mktime (0, 0, 0, (date('m')-1),1)`), годовой (`mktime (0, 0, 0, 1, 1)`). Проблема появилась на неделе. Мне нужно найти время понедельника, который на это неделе.

Попробовал `strtotime("last Monday")`, работает наполовину. Он в принципе работает хорошо во все дни, кроме понедельника. Сегодня же понедельник, новая неделя, а он мне выводит данные за прошлую неделю. Помогите мне пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime('Monday this week')`

Comment: Коротко и ясно. Люблю такие комментарии. Благодарю